Protege import resolution of local files
I'm currently modelling a new ontology and when importing ontologies I noticed a behavior that looks like a bug to me. Here is the process.
I created a base-ontology file that contains a class called BaseClass.  I want to import the base-ontology to a child-ontology file to create ChildClass that is a sub-class of BaseClass. This works as expected.
Lastly I want to import the child-ontology file to my ABox file to instantiate ChildClass. However, Protege won't let me do that. I always get the following error message in the tool:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://www.example.org/base-ontology
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.connect(AbstractOWLParser.java:148)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputStream(AbstractOWLParser.java:113)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
  ERROR  15:56:02  An error occurred whilst extracting the Ontology Id from the imported ontology: {}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.repository.MasterOntologyIDExtractor.getOntologyId(MasterOntologyIDExtractor.java:27)
    at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.ontology.imports.wizard.page.AnticipateOntologyIdPage.checkImport(AnticipateOntologyIdPage.java:109)
    at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.ontology.imports.wizard.page.AnticipateOntologyIdPage.lambda$new$0(AnticipateOntologyIdPage.java:44)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

It seems to me that Protege wants to load the file from a server that doesn't exist (checked the behavior in the Protege source code too).
I checked the catalog-v001.xml file and it is missing the uri tag that indicates were it can find the physical file for base-ontology.ttl but even after adding the tag manually (based on the documentation found here), it still tried to load the import of base-ontology from a resource on the internet.
The Protege version used was 5.6.4 but I also tried it with 5.5.0 with the same results. All files were created with by the Protege editor, no manual tinkering with the files (with the exception of trying to fix the issue as a last step).
If I remove the import statement from the child-ontology.ttl file I can import both ontologies without an issue.
Is this a reproducible bug in Protege and can be recreated on other machines or am I doing something wrong?
Side note: I'm sitting behind a corporate proxy with custom certificates injected into chain which might be part of the issue (but I don't know how since Protege should load the files from my disk).
Here is the file for base-ontology.ttl:
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/base-ontology/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.example.org/base-ontology/> .

<http://www.example.org/base-ontology> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

###  http://www.example.org/base-ontology#BaseClass
:BaseClass rdf:type owl:Class .

Here is the class for child-ontology.ttl:
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/child-ontology/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.example.org/child-ontology/> .

<http://www.example.org/child-ontology> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
                                         owl:imports <http://www.example.org/base-ontology> .

###  http://www.example.org/child-ontology#ChildClass
:ChildClass rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf <http://www.example.org/base-ontology/BaseClass> .

Here is the catalog-v001.xml file that Protege created:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<catalog prefer="public" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <group id="Folder Repository, directory=, recursive=true, Auto-Update=true, version=2" prefer="public" xml:base=""/>
</catalog>

And here is the file were I manually added the location of the physical file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<catalog prefer="public" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <uri id="User Entered Import Resolution" name="http://www.example.org/base-ontology" uri="base-ontology.ttl"/>
    <group id="Folder Repository, directory=, recursive=true, Auto-Update=true, version=2" prefer="public" xml:base=""/>
</catalog>


As you tagged this with both Protege and owl-api, I initially thought this could be an issue with AutoIRIMapper (the OWLAPI class that is charged with loading local copies of ontologies found in a specified folder).
AutoIRIMapper does not support ttl files, though, and you're entering just one entry in the file, not a folder, so I expect AutoIRIMapper is not part of the problem.
This could be a Protege issue, then - but I'm guessing you need a full file URL instead of just the file name. Have you tried adding
file:///<local path in your computer>/base-ontology.ttl

to your registry file?

Hi Ignazio, thanks for the reply. Tried it with your workaround as well and it didn't work.
The behavior is quite strange. The indirect import works for a different ontology file and I never had issues in the past but for some reason these files (and the original ontology files) seem to be cursed.
Usually I get asked by Protege that the tool can't find the file online and if I want to use a local file instead but for some reason it doesn't do that for these files.
I flagged it also as OWL API because in the source code Protege uses OWL API to load the files so I thought it might be that.

Try opening the local file on its own, I'm wondering if the file is truncated or has a syntactic error.

Opening the file is not an issue. All the files were created with Protégé itself and were not modified manually. I can also just remove the import statements and import them as a flat list into the ABox file (which I use as a workaround). The problem only occurs if the imported file has an indirect import in it.
I also tried a newer Protégé version from a fresh download but it has the same issue.
Is there a way to invalidate the caches of Protégé? I already tried to delete the catalog-v001.xml but to no avail.
